# lighthttpd proxy rules to allow for snap-shot testing and amazon monitoring

Tags: amazon-ec2, lighttpd

I use this rule for my proxy:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
    proxy.balance = "round-robin" proxy.server = ( "/" =>
        ( ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 9000 ) ) )
}
```

Because I'm allowing any host to go to my proxy, I have the flexibility to test a snap-shot VM using the Amazon provided URL.

The problem is, I get error from missed requests like : manager.html,  azenv.php, phpMyAdmin.translators.html, user.soapCaller.bs

I wonder if these are really all from Amazon....  I assume azenv.php must provide some information to the AWS console.

What is the best way to allow Amazon to check up on the host while still allowing me to clone and test new hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those requests are not from Amazon, they're just random script kiddies searching for commonly exploited installed apps. You'll see them on any site on the public internet given enough time.

Amazon doesn't monitor your site via HTTP requests unless it's behind an Elastic Load Balancer, and in the case of an ELB, you pick what URL it checks.